# Finding scope inside ng-repeat for ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have a very complex nested angular object. 
Now at the end of the object ng-click didn't work.

I read on how angular scope works, and I get that ng-click create a child scope for each item in the loop. 
What I don't get is if the ng-click can't find the function I try to call in the scope, how does it find the function that returns the scope.

Here what I mean :

```
mainApp.controller('fileController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.function_ngclick_cant_get = function (){
    // stuff here
    };

    $scope.getMyCtrlScope = function() {
        return $scope;   
   }
}
```

Here's the btn

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="getMyCtrlScope().function_ngclick_cant_get();">call function</button>
```

If I call 'function_ngclick_cant_get' directly it doesn't work. 
If I call it like in the example it works.

But why does it works ? They are in the same scope.

Comment: It works. U must have a typeo or something https://plnkr.co/edit/bXgN9MDGq1IFkOrXIUnc?p=preview

Comment: I know it works... I just want to understand why.

Comment: ok I will try to explain more - when the object han many nested ng-repeats the nc-click stops wroking. 

I have about 6.
See here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513069/finding-scope-inside-ng-repeat-for-ng-click

I fixed the problem - I just not shore why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I might be wrong because I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but why are you setting up function that returns $scope? You could simple do without any returns or scopes.

When adding properties to the $scope object in the controller, the view (HTML) gets access to these properties. 
So your code should look like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="function_ngclick_cant_get();">call function</button>
```

You can check on w3schools about scope: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_scopes.asp

**UPDATE:**

I prepared some dummy code to show that you can use ng-click on multiple ng-repeats:

https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/2e4w3yuo/10/

So there's no need for functions that return $scope and seems like you have a problem in your code somewhere, post more code put it on fiddle or somewhere and we may be able to help.

Comment: ok I will try to explain more - when the object has many nested ng-repeats the nc-click stops working. I have about 6. See here :stackoverflow.com/questions/46513069/… I fixed the problem - I just not shore why it works.

And btw calling the function directly doesn't work. Not in the full code.

Comment: I updated my answer you can clearly see that it doesn't really matter how many ng-repeats I have there I can still access $scope and functions on it.